# sampleDocument is not assignable to type T

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to get a hang of OOP with it.

I have the following code:

```
import {ReadOnlyDocument} from "../../docs/read-only.document";
import {IReadOnlyRepository} from "./abstract/Iread-only.repository";
import {sampleDocument} from "../../docs/sampleDocument";

export abstract class ReadOnlyRepository<T extends ReadOnlyDocument> implements IReadOnlyRepository<T> {

    public getById(id: string): T {
        let sample: sampleDocument = new sampleDocument('',
            new Date(),
            '',
            new Date(),
            '');
        /*Line of code that brings the error.*/
        return sample;
    }

}
```

However I keep getting the error **`sampleDocument` is not assignable to type T** and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have added other possibly relevant code below.

```
import {ReadOnlyDocument} from "./read-only.document";

export class sampleDocument extends ReadOnlyDocument{

}
```

```
export abstract class Document {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public createdDate: Date,
        public createdBy: string,
        public updatedDate: Date,
        public updatedBy: string
    ) { }
}
```

```
import { Document } from './abs/document'

export abstract class ReadOnlyDocument extends Document{

}
```

```
import {ReadOnlyDocument} from "../../../docs/read-only.document";
import { IRepository } from "./Irepository";

export interface IReadOnlyRepository<T extends ReadOnlyDocument> extends IRepository<T> {
    getById(id: string): T;
}
```

```
import {Document} from "../../../domain/documents/abstract/document";

export interface IRepository<T extends Document>  {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` is any *subtype* of `ReadOnlyDocument`, so e.g. if you had a `ReadOnlyPDF` and that extends `ReadOnlyDocument`, then you could construct a `ReadOnlyRepository<ReadOnlyPDF>`, and you expect it to return a `ReadOnlyPDF` from `getById`, however it only returns a `ReadOnlyDocument`.

Comment: Makes sense so how can I have it such that I can create and return a new generic type (`sampleDocument` in this case) but also ensure that it of the abstract type ReadOnlyDocument? I read about passing constructor functions here [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). But it doesn't say how that would work if your constructor needs to have parameters passed into it.

Comment: @kikanye I'd recommend to omit the generic type, then also omit the return type of the method.